# import fixed width data file in postgresql table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

we have fixed width data text file and need to load into postgresql table.
data example:

```
123450000026780123456ABCDEFGHI
```

This should insert into table like:

```
id 12345
acnum 00000267
actag 80123456
firstname ABCDE
lastname FGHI
```

Please suggest me how to import fixed width data into postgresql table.

Comment: The easiest option is to load the file into a staging table that has a single text column. Then use  SQL to split the value and insert it into the real table

Comment: alternatively convert from SDF to CSV and then import that.

Comment: Maybe [pgloader](https://pgloader.io) offers the functionality you need.

Comment: Also, you could do pre-process the lines from the file using the `PROGRAM` option, may be with  unix  command lines(like awk/cut etc).